# Delphi print a custom area of a form

Tags: delphi, printing

I have a form which I need to print but only a certain section of it and then enlarge it (increase the scale). So far I have the following code:

```
procedure TForm1.PrintButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
 var
    printDialog : TPrintDialog;

  begin
  printDialog := TPrintDialog.Create(Form1);
  if printDialog.Execute then
    begin
      Printer.Orientation := poLandscape;    //Better fit than portrait
      Form1.PrintScale:=poPrintToFit;        
      Form1.Print;

    end;
  end;
```

However, this prints the whole form. I've googled around and found a few different things that might help but I'm not sure how to use them:

GetFormImage - Is there a way of selecting a specific area with this or does it just take the whole form?

Using a rectangle with given coordinates e.g  rectangle1:= rect(Left, Top, Right, Bottom);  but then how do I print scale the rectangle to a larger size and print it? As well, seen as though Delphi only gives Left and Top properties, is Right just another name for the furthest left value you want to go to?

**UPDATE:**
I have tried to create a custom bitmap and then stretch it but I'm not using the strechdraw correctly. It doesn't actually stretch when printed:

```
  procedure TForm1.PrintButtonClick(Sender: TObject);

  var
    printDialog: TPrintDialog;
    Rectangle, stretched: TRect;
    Bitmap: TBitmap;
  begin
    Bitmap := TBitmap.Create;
    try
      Rectangle := Rect(0, 90, 1450, 780);
      stretched := Rect(0, 0, 5000, 3000); //what numbers do i put in here for streching it?
      Bitmap.SetSize(Form1.Width, Form1.Height);
      Bitmap.Canvas.CopyRect(Rectangle, Form1.Canvas, Rectangle);
      Bitmap.Canvas.StretchDraw(stretched, Bitmap); //not sure how to use this
    finally
      printDialog := TPrintDialog.Create(Form1);
      if printDialog.Execute then
      begin
        with printer do
        begin
          BeginDoc;
          Canvas.Draw(0, 90, Bitmap);
          EndDoc;
        end;
      end;
      Bitmap.Free;
    end;
  end;
```

Is the try and finally necessary?
When I printed without the stretchdraw it was really small but when I printed with the stretchdraw, a lot of the image was missing so I must be using it wrong

Comment: What "new layout"? It's worked the same way for at least 4-5 years since I've been using this website. Select your code and then click the "Format Code" button.

Comment: @JerryDodge I knew Id changed something. I switched to the mobile site by accident

Comment: You misunderstand the purpose of TPrintDialog. It simply configures the printer options; it doesn't handle the task of actually printing. If you need other than the default behavior of TForm.Print, you're going to need to code it yourself. And the right value of a rectangle is left + width, just like bottom is top + height.

Comment: No. You can copy the rectangle you want to an image, scale that image appropriately for the printer page, and then print that image. There are existing questions here about capturing a portion of a window using Delphi, as well as questions about scaling an image. (It's usually much easier to use a proper reporting library and just produce the output on that report that you want from the screen, but I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish exactly, so that may not be an option for you.)

Comment: I'm going to delete my previous comments to clean up the comment clutter. Hope you got what you needed from them first.

Comment: @KenWhite I've changed the code again, does it seem like I've looked at what you put in now?

Comment: You can select/combine clip regions to DC-s. createPolygonRgn(), createRectRgn(), selectClipRgn( hdc, hrgn ); combineClipRgn( destRgn, srcRgn1, srcRgn2, boolOpType ); deleteObject( hrgn ); formDC := getDC( form.handle ) or bmpDC := bmp.canvas.handle;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of your `stretched` variable and the `Bitmap.Canvas.StretchDraw` (you can also get rid of the `TPrintDialog` if you'd like).

```
// Capture your bitmap content here, and then use this code to scale and print.
Printer.Orientation := poLandscape;
Printer.BeginDoc;
Printer.Canvas.StretchDraw(Rect(0, 0, Printer.PageWidth, Printer.PageHeight), Bitmap);
Printer.EndDoc;
```